Pandas Extract Phone Number if it is in Correct Format
I have a column that has phone numbers. They are usually formatted in (555) 123-4567 but sometimes they are in a different format or they are not proper numbers. I am trying to convert this field to have just the numbers, removing any non-numeric characters (if there are 10 numbers).
How can I apply a function that says if there are 10 numbers in this field, extract just the numbers?
I tried to use:
df['PHONE'] = df['PHONE'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False)

But this just extracts the first chunk of numbers (the area code). How do I pull all the numbers and only run this extraction if there are exactly 10 numbers in the field?
My expected output would be 5551234567

What if there are not 10 numbers?

Figured it out. I created a function that I apply to my phone # field
def extractNums(number):
    new_number = list(filter(str.isnumeric, number))
    if len(new_number) == 10:
        return "".join(new_number)
    else:
        return number

df['PHONE'] = df['PHONE'].apply(extractNums)


The most robust is likely to delete everything but digits with str.replace and the \D regex (=everything but digits):
df['PHONE'] = df['PHONE'].str.replace(r'\D+', '', regex=True)

Example (with the output as PHONE2 for clarity):
            PHONE      PHONE2
0  (555) 123-4567  5551234567

If you only want to replace the rows in which there are exactly 10 digits (and leave the others unchanged):
s = df['PHONE'].str.replace(r'\D+', '', regex=True)

df.loc[s.str.len().eq(10), 'PHONE2'] = s

If you only want to keep the rows in which there are only 10 digits (and replace the others by NaN):
s = df['PHONE'].str.replace(r'\D+', '', regex=True)

df['PHONE'] = s.where(s.str.len().eq(10))


df['PHONE'] = df['PHONE'].str.replace(r'\)|\(| |-', '', regex=True)

Will replace (), Space and - with regex. Just add all other undesired characters in your set. If the undesired Parts are regex syntax characters escape them with \

Telephone numbers can exceed 10 digits due to the country code. (In the US this is most common with 1-800-555-5555 numbers since they carry over the North American +1 country code.)
I would filter out all non-digit characters (regex \D) and remove invalid phone numbers. The longest possible ITU-compliant phone number is 15 digits. (There are apparently some numbers in Germany which exceed this.) The shortest with country code is 8.
s = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('''pn
+1 123 456 7890
+44 123 456 7890
+1 (123) 456-7890
11234567890
441234567890
456456465654654465
123'''))
s['pn'].str.replace(r'\D', '', regex=True).mask(
    lambda s: s.str.len().gt(15) | s.str.len().lt(8), np.nan)

Yields
0     11234567890
1    441234567890
2     11234567890
3     11234567890
4    441234567890
5             NaN
6             NaN
Name: pn, dtype: object

For better verification, because phone numbers are complicated, you may want to consider phonenumbers, which ports the Java version of Google's libphonenumber. The documentation should be clear on how you would parse, validate, and reformat phone numbers.
